# PYTHON convert mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM TO mm/dd/yy

Tags: python

I use PYTHON do dateframe merge my output is:
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns].
I expert it to excel file, the Date column shows like: 3/2/2020  12:00:00 AM
Is that possible to convert 3/2/2020  12:00:00 AM to 3/2/2020

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by this:

`df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_date'], format='%m/%d/%y')`

The first part of the code, get the column date in the dataframe. The 2nd part convert it to the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you need to change in Excel, not Python. Use the number format dropdown to select your preferred date format.

Comment: The date is stored in an Excel file as a number without any formatting applied.  The format is only used when Excel displays it.